# GTK Volumen button icon show initial value c++

Tags: c++, gtk3, volume

```
GtkWidget *volumen = gtk_volume_button_new();
GtkAdjustment *ajuste = gtk_adjustment_new(50,0,100,1,0,0);
gtk_scale_button_set_adjustment(GTK_SCALE_BUTTON(volumen),ajuste);
```

The problem i have is the icon, the icon shows mute at the beginning of the app, not the 50% of volumen icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe if you add `gtk_scale_button_set_value(GTK_SCALE_BUTTON(volumen),50);`

Comment: Yes i work just put GtkAdjustment                                                                 *ajuste = gtk_adjustment_new(0,0,100,1,0,0);   at 0 before set the value with gtk_scale_button_set_value(GTK_SCALE_BUTTON(volumen),50);